# Duplicating an edge in ogdf::GraphCopy

Tags: c++, graph

I'm using OGDF version 2012.07.

I have a GraphCopy which represents a copy of a Graph instance. It holds references to the original nodes and edges when operating on the graph copy. In the [documentation of GraphCopy](http://www.ogdf.net/doc-ogdf/classogdf_1_1_graph_copy.html#details), it says:

> Copies of graphs supporting edge splitting.
>
> The class **GraphCopy** represents a copy of a graph and maintains a mapping between the nodes and edges of the original graph to the copy and vice versa.
>
> [...]

There is a method [ogdf::GraphCopy::newEdge(edge eOrig)](http://www.ogdf.net/doc-ogdf/classogdf_1_1_graph_copy.html#afa878a77d5ce6b1a85a532cff6350fe1) which is documented as follows:

> Creates a new edge (*v,w*) with original edge *eOrig*.

The method is implemented as follows:

```
edge GraphCopy::newEdge(edge eOrig)
{
    OGDF_ASSERT(eOrig != 0 && eOrig->graphOf() == m_pGraph);
    OGDF_ASSERT(m_eCopy[eOrig].empty()); // no support for edge splitting!

    edge e = Graph::newEdge(m_vCopy[eOrig->source()], m_vCopy[eOrig->target()]);
    m_eCopy[m_eOrig[e] = eOrig].pushBack(e);

    return e;
}
```

In the second assertion, the number of associated edge copies of the edge *eOrig* in the original graph has to be zero, which is only possible when the edge copy has been deleted, since initially (when the GraphCopy was initialized with an original graph) all edges in the graph copy are associated with the corresponding original edge in the original graph; thus, `m_eCopy[eOrig].empty()` is false for all edges.

How am I supposed to **duplicate an edge** in the graph copy while not changing the original graph?

Comment: Just using `Graph::newEdge(e.source(), e.target())` solves the edge duplication problem for me. I let the question unanswered since this is only a workaround for me in which the newly inserted edge is not associated with any original edge in the GraphCopy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not follow your explanations about the implementation. When I browse the source code [GraphCopy.h](http://www.ogdf.net/doc-ogdf/_graph_copy_8h_source.html) on the OGDF website (which says its for 2012.07.), I see totally different classes. There is one class **GraphCopy** (which is an interface for derrived GraphCopy classes supporting edge splitting) and another class **GraphCopySimple** which doesn't support edge spliting.

So my advice is to check if you really have the right version.

The method *newEdge(edge eOrig)* in **GraphCopySimple** looks like it does what you want:

```
edge newEdge(edge eOrig) {
    OGDF_ASSERT(eOrig != 0 && eOrig->graphOf() == m_pGraph);
    edge e = Graph::newEdge(m_vCopy[eOrig->source()], m_vCopy[eOrig->target()]);
    m_eCopy[m_eOrig[e] = eOrig] = e;
    return e;
}
```

But there is one issue remaining. **GraphCopySimple** has no implementation for the constructors, so I guess it meant as abstract base class, so you need to derive your own GraphCopy-class and implement the missing functions.

Comment: Note that I'm talking about edge duplication. GraphCopy::split works fine. But duplicating an edge isn't supported (two edges belonging to one original edge, where the two edges are parallel). This is what I think at the moment. I just was confused when I read the comment behind the assertion in GraphCopy.cpp (not .h!): "no support for edge splitting!", which 1) clearly is a contradiction to the objective of GraphCopy ("Copies of graphs supporting edge splitting") and 2) is not the operation we talk about when creating a new edge in parallel to an already existing edge.

Comment: GraphCopySimple::newEdge(edge eOrig) totally does *not* what I want. It creates a new edge and assigns it uniquely to the given original edge, so previously assigned edges are lost.

Comment: ... but anyways, thanks for your answer and welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Comment: I am sorry! I just read the doxygen documentation online, and did not even found a .cpp. In the SVN there is of course an .cpp and now I CAN follow your question. Hmm... good point :)